# Разбить число на несколько случайных диапазонов

Tags: php, c#, массивы, случайные-числа

Есть исходное число, к примеру 100.
Есть рандом, к примеру 5-50.
Надо разбить 100 на случайные числа в диапазоне 5-50 которые в сумме дадут 100.
На выходе получаем `35, 50, 15`
Целый день голову ломаю, не могу придумать как решить.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вычитайте из 100 случайное число, пока не достигните нуля.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, а если последнее вычитаемое не войдёт в нужный диапазон чисел?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Ну, сделать дополнительную проверку и перероллить число если не подходит. Я примерно объяснил как решать такую задачу.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, однако количество таких "роллов" неограниченно :D

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Да, а еще нужно будет шлифовать алгоритм, чтобы частота выпадения чисел была ровная. =)

Comment: [Пара вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983006/) разбиения на конкретное число частей

Comment: Спасибо всем за участие. Как я и думал, без "возможнобесконечного" цикла тут не обойтись.

Comment: @Dr. Ну я как-то обошёлся.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на C#, методом подбора ряда рандомных чисел:

```
int number = 100;
int min = 5;
int max = 50;
        
Random rng = new Random();            
List<int> numsList = new List<int>();

do
{
    if (numsList.Sum() > number)
    {
        numsList.RemoveAt(0);
        continue;
    }
    numsList.Add(rng.Next(min, max + 1));
} while (numsList.Sum() != number);

foreach (int item in numsList) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: Если `numsList.Sum()` попадет в диапазон от 96 до 99, то вы попадете в бесконечный цикл. И `rng.Next(min, max)` вам сейчас выдает числа `0..49`, и никогда не выдаст `50`.

Comment: Почему? Следующая итерация добавит к списку еще одно число, что вызовет переполнение суммы, на следующей итерации первый элемент из списка удалится.

Comment: Окей, а потом что будет? Снова число, снова переполнение, снова удаление, а потом?

Comment: Снова и снова, пока не подберет список чисел сумма которого требуется. В среднем за 30-50 итераций подбирает с данными параметрами.

Comment: Как оно подберет число, от 1 до 4, если минимальное 5?

Comment: Не понимаю, причем тут числа от 1 до 4?

Comment: Все, точно, извините. `RemoveAt(0)` удаляет первый элемент, а я вочему-то прочитал как последний.

Comment: Кстати, почему бы не использовать очередь `Queue<T>` в таком случае? Смотрелось бы элегантней. :)

Comment: Можно и Queue. Просто List первым под руку подвернулся, как более распространенный в использовании вариант. =)